# How to print the data in byte array as characters?

Tags: java, arrays

In my byte array I have the *hash* values of a message which consists of some negative values and also positive values. Positive values are being printed easily by using the `(char)byte[i]` statement.

Now how can I get the negative value?

Comment: What do you by by "as characters" exactly? Decimal? Hex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well if you're happy printing it in decimal, you could just make it positive by masking:

```
int positive = bytes[i] & 0xff;
```

If you're printing out a hash though, it would be more conventional to use hex. There are plenty of other questions on Stack Overflow addressing converting binary data to a hex string in Java.

Answer (score 294):

How about [`Arrays.toString(byteArray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[]))?

Here's some compilable code:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[] { -1, -128, 1, 127 };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
```

Output:

```
[-1, -128, 1, 127]
```

Why re-invent the wheel...

Comment: In Kotlin it is `byteArray.contentToString()`

Answer (score 25):

If you want to print the bytes as chars you can use the String constructor.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { -1, -128, 1, 127 };
System.out.println(new String(bytes, 0));
```

Comment: The constructor String(byte[], int) is deprecated. Use String(byte[], Charset) instead, for example new String(bytes, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")).

Answer (score 24):

Try it:

```
public static String print(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[ ");
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        sb.append(String.format("0x%02X ", b));
    }
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Example:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 
        (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x2E, (byte) 0x6E, (byte) 0x30
    };

    System.out.println("bytes = " + print(bytes));
 }
```

Output: `bytes = [ 0x01 0xFF 0x2E 0x6E 0x30 ]`

Comment: This is one of the better options if you want to print the characters as _hex_.

Comment: looks like it prints them as numbers

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to print the content similar to HexDump. I think your solution is the most suitable solution for my situation!

Answer (score 12):

Try this one : `new String(byte[])`

Answer (score 8):

```
byte[] buff = {1, -2, 5, 66};
for(byte c : buff) {
    System.out.format("%d ", c);
}
System.out.println();
```

gets you

```
1 -2 5 66
```

Answer (score 2):

in Kotlin you can use :

`println(byteArray.contentToString())`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write binary data to the standard output you can use a FileOutputStream object.

```java
FileOutputStream stdout = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
byte arr[] = {-16, -97, -104, -118, 10};
stdout.write(arr);
```

Trying to convert binary data to a string runs the risk of mangling it through unwanted codepage conversion.

Of course, it's probably better to avoid sending binary data to the standard output, or if you're writing ha ash value to print it in hexadecimal.