# Byte array to string returns null

Tags: java, string, encryption, byte

I'm writing a program to encrypt data.
I created a random IV this way:

```
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
```

And used it for the cipher. 
Now I want to store this IV in a configuration file so I can transport it to the decrypting function, and for that I need to convert the IV to a string format.

I used `byte curIV[] = cipher.getIV();` to get the IV and printed it's value to the console, but when I convert it to string,
 this way `String ivString = new String(curIV);`, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hey, what is a IV?

Comment: Hello, IV is an Initialization vector and it's transferred as a parameter to the cipher. You can read more here- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector

Comment: The byte-array may include non-printable characters - you could use [Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])) - see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6463665/6287240)

Comment: But what do you expect it to have? i don't see any code adding any value to the byte array

Comment: @LenosV The bytearray is initialized to 16x0 in the array. Its a valid IV but not very secure!

Comment: You are printing nul chars `\0`, which are one of many invisible chars. Instead, print the bytes as hexadecimal, which will always make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
```

This creates an array of 16 bytes initialized to `0`. `0x00` is not a printable character (it's a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters)), so you might have trouble seeing it printed (either problem in printing or problem with how you view the printed result).

Depending on your needs, you may want to:

- Print it using `Arrays.toString()` as suggested by @TmTron (but expect to not see the printed result properly in some programs, you'll need hexa viewer to see it properly)
- Print it in hexadecimal representation
- Encode it using [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Comment: Your recommendations are good. But, the point is it doesn't make sense to call 0x00 any kind of character. Not text is not text.

Answer (score 3):

### Your code works correctly

The array is initialized with a size of `16`, where each of this `16` bytes is a `0`.

Now, lets look at the ascii table to find the correct character for `0`.

[image]

Aha, the character for `0` is character `NUL`.

If you do a `new String(cipher.getIV());` you become a valid String value containing no informations.

### How to solve

Simply convert a String of size 16 to bytes.

```
byte[] ivBytes = "123456789abcdef".getBytes();
```

### Security

Computers are good in calculation but bad in random values. Random values are hard to estimated. That makes random values important for security. That makes the 16x0 byte array a bad idea.

### Configuration

Finally you need to store that information to the configuration. Hm, as this character is not readable character its hard to save this to a text-based configuration.

Focusing on security you should not allow 16x0 IVs. So 16x0 IVs must not be able to be stored to the configuration.

### Suggestion

Use this instead:

```
String ivString = "blahblah"; // read from configuration if required
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivString.getBytes());
ivString = new String(iv.getIV()); //write to configuration if required
```

Comment: So you suggest limiting the bytes in the IV to alphanumeric / printable character values? Wouldn't that reduce the possible combinations from `2^128` to `95^16` ~ `2^112`?

Comment: @JiriTousek Yes it does reduce (95^16???). The security will be improoved because you are forced to use a `IV > 0`. But it does violates the Single-Version-Of-Truth in this way that it is not clear who defines the value-range of the IV: the Spec or the Impl.

Comment: From my point of view, if the spec sais `0` is a valid, atomic, authentic value (so a good value), then I hope impl knows better :D.

Comment: The problem was indeed a wrong initialization of the IV, Thanks a lot!